# Apply hover text design when hovering corresponding image

Tags: css

so I use a design for the text of my products when I hover on them
http://www.screencast.com/t/X04O6Vn1

```
.prodThumb .title &gt; span:hover {
    color: #CA681D !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

Now I would like this settings to apply also when the user go on the image corresponding to this product name
http://www.screencast.com/t/6qouh6CkO

But I'm unsure I could figure this out with just CSS code.
I haven't found any selectors that would work

My idea was to find the selector and then put the following code

```
selector:hover {
    color: #CA681D !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

I'm working on this URL https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/africain

Any ideas that would help?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: What does your html structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
.imgWrap:hover ~ .title > span:first-child {
    color: #CA681D !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

the "~" is the general sibling combinator: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much, as well as the lesson :D !

Comment: no pbm! can you vote for the answer if it helped you

Comment: I don't have any reputation yet, but I'll definitely when I can :)

Comment: Hey, actually I have one issue which is created by your code, and I can't explain it.
Sometimes, it also underlines the element "nombre of customer comments" as you can see from this image: http://www.screencast.com/t/K9l3MNQyfgt from this URL: https://www.tresor-ethnique.com/collections/celtique. I tried to play with the different selectors but couldn't get rid of it. You have any idea related to that?

Comment: Pas grave ;-) I updated the answer to only select the first span under the title div (.imgWrap:hover ~ .title > span:first-child)  I added  ">" sign to be sure that only span of the first level are select and no nested ones

Comment: Again, I didn't know this subtility, I thought "first child" would be enough :) Thank you very much !